# Strongloop android sdk custom method error

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Trying to reach an custom method on my server using an android client create a bad request error.

Here is the custom method on the server (tested with strongloop explorer):

```
Question.remoteMethod(
    'top', {
        http: {path: '/top', verb: 'get'},
        accepts: [
                    {arg : 'start', type: 'number'},
                    {arg: 'pagination', type: 'number'}

                ],
        returns: {arg: 'questions', type: 'array'},
        description: ['Returns an array obj the latest added questions']
    }
);
```

Code  in the android Question repository :

```
@Override
public RestContract createContract() {

    RestContract contract = super.createContract();

    contract.addItem(
        new RestContractItem("/" + getNameForRestUrl() + "/top?" +
            "start=" + ":start" + "&pagination=" + ":pagination", "GET"),
        getClassName() + ".top");

    return contract;
}

public void top(int start, int pagination, ListCallback<Question> cb) {
    Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    params.put("start", start);
    params.put("pagination", pagination);
    invokeStaticMethod("top", params,
            new JsonArrayParser<Question>(this, cb));
}
```

When I use this following code to test the created request url :

```
RestContract contract = this.createContract();
Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        params.put("start", 0);
        params.put("pagination", 2);
        String t = contract.getUrl("/" + getNameForRestUrl() + "/top?" +
                "start=" + ":start" + "&pagination=" + ":pagination", params);
```

t is: "*/Questions/top?start=0&pagination=2*" which is the right url (according to strongloop explorer).
Still, the use of the fucntion TOP returns a bad request error.

Do you have any idea why I got an error, and how I should modify the function to get the results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer. The error was within the Question Repository.

Here is the right peace of code :

```
@Override
public RestContract createContract() {

    RestContract contract = super.createContract();

    contract.addItem(
        new RestContractItem("/" + getNameForRestUrl() + "/top", "GET"),
        getClassName() + ".top");
}

public void top(int start, int pagination, ListCallback<Question> cb) {
    Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    params.put("start", start);
    params.put("pagination", pagination);
    invokeStaticMethod("top", params,
        new JsonResponseParser<Question>(this, cb, "questions"));
}
```

You must not specify filter when you create the rest contract as the using the top method below will automaticaly add the parameters given to the parameters Map as a filter with the form :
http://serverip:port/api/Questions/top?filter=value1&filter2=value2